# Binding input box value and passing to a component

Tags: ember.js

It seems that I am stuck while learning Ember.js.

It's possible that I am greatly misusing the components, or perhaps I am missing something small - either way, please help!

Here is what I would like:

- An input box that filters the table of systems that I have
- I would like the input to be its own component instead of coupling it with the table. I feel like this would be much easier if the table was inside the component? I like the idea of decoupling them if possible.
- I am also using another custom component to sort the data (hence why I'm using `arrangedContent` instead of model)

I am having 3 problems:

1. The value of the input does not seem to be properly bound to my controller - ie when I type something in the input box it doesn't seem to be reflected in the controller `filterString` value
2. Because filtering and setting the list is done behind the `keyPress` on the input, initially the table is empty. How would I go about populating the table before a key is pressed?
3. The call to `this.set('filteredItems', items)` doesn't reflect the changes to the table. I tried using `propertyWillChange` and `propertyDidChange` but still no luck.
4. (optional) ideally it would be nice to have `filterString` and `filteredItems` contained inside the component also, but I suspect that's not possible. I was thinking more for easy portability

Here is the jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qicuq/1/edit

**template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/filter-input">
  {{input type="search" placeholder="Filter..." value=value}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{filter-input value=filterString}}
  <br/>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>System Name</th>
      <th>Owner</th>
    </tr>
    {{#each item in filteredItems}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.owner.username}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</script>
```

**js**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  filterableProperties: ['name', 'owner.username'],
  filteredItems: [],
  filterString: null,
});

App.FilterInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  arrangedContentBinding: 'controller.arrangedContent',
  filterStringBinding: 'controller.filterString',
  filteredItemsBinding: 'controller.filteredItems',
  filterablePropertiesBinding: 'controller.filterableProperties',

  keyPress: function() {
    var items = this.get('arrangedContent');

    console.log('-------------');
    console.log('items ' + items);
    console.log('value ' + this.get('value'));
    console.log('filterString ' + this.get('filterString'));
    console.log('valueBinding ' + this.get('valueBinding'));
    console.log('filterableProperties ' + this.get('filterableProperties'));

    // filter 'items' here by the value of 'filter-input' and whether or not the property is in the filterableProperties list

    console.log('filteredItems-before ' + this.get('filteredItems'));
    //this.propertyWillChange('filteredItems');
    this.set('filteredItems', items);
    //this.propertyDidChange('filteredItems');
    console.log('filteredItems-after ' + this.get('filteredItems'));
  },
});
```

**console output when typing 'a' into input box**

```
"-------------"
"items [object Object],[object Object]"
"filterString null"
"value null"
"valueBinding Ember.Binding<ember274>(_parentView.context.filterString -> value)"
"filterableProperties name,owner.username"
"filteredItems-before "
"filteredItems-after [object Object],[object Object]"
```

Thanks guys, any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the searching to work for you with the following modifications:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({   
  filteredItems: function() {
    var content = this.get("content");
    var filterString = this.get("filterString");
    if (filterString) {
      return content.filter(function(item) {
        return item.name.indexOf(filterString) === 0;
      });
    } else {
      return content;
    } 
  }.property("filterString"),
  filterString: null
});

App.FilterInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  filterStringBinding: 'controller.filterString',    
  keyUp: function() {
    this.set("filterString", this.get("value"));
  }
});
```

Here is the [JsBin fiddle](http://jsbin.com/dazevipe/1/edit)!

I hope this answers your problem.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your help. Is it possible to move that logic from the controller into the component? I would like to use the component in a few different places and it would be great if I didn't have to repeat that logic everwhere.

Comment: I have figured it out, thanks! The key was using the keyUp action. Here is the working JsBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mofakide/1/edit